# How to use external JavaScript file in Facebook application development?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

How can I use the external JavaScript in Facebook application development?

Actually I want to use the Ajax tab feature in my application.

Comment: What do you mean by "external java script in facebook application development"? Could you elaborate on this more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hai vipinsahu,

If you want to embed an external .js file, you'll have to specify the absolute path. Not only: Facebook will keep a copy of your script, even if you modify it, so you'll have to put a timestamp in the url to force a cache refresh.

For example, if you want to embed a script in your index.phtml:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('http://www.yourserver.com/fbapp/scripts/js.js?v=' . filemtime('scripts/js.js')) ?>
```

n this way Facebook will load the script from the url: http://www.yourserver.com/fbapp/scripts/js.js?v=1231707071.
When you'll edit the file, the number will change and FB will reload it.

for ref see this  [embed an external .js file in a facebook application](http://blog.madarco.net/91/build-a-facebook-application-with-zend-framework/)

Comment: Thanks Pandiya Chendur u save my life